# RegEx to match starting element containing specific sequence of characters

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I have this XML document fragment..

> `<fsm>
>       <fparameters>
>         <fparameter name="fsOAPath"><%#sqlscalar:select dbo.fsOaPath(<%OrderId%>)%></fparameter>
>       </fparameters>
>       <do>
>         <action>
>           <context source="/notification/fsm/parameters/parameter[@name='fsOAPath']" destination="/notification/message/parameter[@name='Body']" />
>         </action>
>       </do>
>     </fsm>
>     <message>
>       <parameter name="AlternateViews">text/html</parameter>
>       <parameter name="Attachements" />
>        <parameter name="Body" />
>        <parameter name="Sender">Expresslane <%# sqlscalar:select @@servername%> </parameter>
>       <parameter name="Subject" />
>       <parameter name="SubjectEncoding"/>
>       <parameter name="To"><%#sqlscalar:select dbo.fsEmailReceipientOfOrder(<%OrderId%>)%> </parameter>
>     </message>
>   </fsm>`

And this Regex

```
(?<vars>(?><%[\s]*)\w+(?>[\s]*%>))
```

which maches <%OrderId%> text
in the nodes 
     /fsm/fparameters/fparameter[@name='fsOAPath"] 
and  /fsm/message/parameter/[@name='To']
What is the regex for including the 
local node's local name of fparameter and parameter

Comment: It's probably better to use XPath in this scenario.

Comment: I dont understand the `(?<vars>` part of your regex. Maybe a mistake?

Comment: @sSebatianH, That is to name the captures to group named 'vars'.

Comment: @VivinPaliath, Unfortunately not.. The RegEx remain same across any xml document but the xml node names can vary..

Comment: Use XPath or an XML parser.  Trying to parse XML with regexes is a path to long-term sorrow.

Comment: @Andy Lester & Vivin,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
<(?<localName>[^\s]+).+(?<vars>(?><%[\s]*)\w+(?>[\s]*%>))
```

#### Demo

http://regex101.com/r/zI7zW8